# Why does autoscaling group creation require two terraform runs, if using for_each to iterate?

Tags: dependencies, autoscaling, idempotent

When I apply terraform to create launch configuration and auto-scaling groups using `for_each` and `each.value`, referencing a `map` variable, creating multiples of each, with the ASGs referencing LCs of the same `each.value`, the ASGs are not created on the first run, and a second run is required to create them.

I have tried changing `name` to `name_prefix` and I have tried adding a `lifecycle { create_before_destroy = true }` block in the ASG, but the problem remains.

I am using this solution so that I can use the `bootstrap.sh` EKS script to register a label based on `each.value`, so that we can use `nodeAffinity` in kubernetes.

```
variable "node_types" {
  description = "Each node type, used for affinities, taints, tolerations"
  type = "map"
  default = {
    key1 = "web",
    key2 = "worker"
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "tf_eks" {
  for_each = var.node_types

  name                        = "${var.cluster_name}-${each.value}-lc"
  iam_instance_profile        = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.node.name}"
  image_id                    = "${data.aws_ami.eks-worker.id}"
  instance_type               = var.node_instance_type
  root_block_device {
  volume_size                 = "1000"                      # root volume size of workers instances.
  volume_type                 = "gp2"
  }
  security_groups             = ["${aws_security_group.tf-eks-node.id}"]
  user_data_base64            = "${base64encode(<<USERDATA
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh --apiserver-endpoint '${aws_eks_cluster.tf_eks.endpoint}' --b64-cluster-ca '${aws_eks_cluster.tf_eks.certificate_authority.0.data}' '${var.cluster_name}' --kubelet-extra-args '--node-labels=type=${each.value}'
USERDATA
)}"
  key_name                    = "${var.keypair_name}"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "tf_eks" {
  for_each = var.node_types

  name                 = "${var.cluster_name}-${each.value}-asg"
  desired_capacity     = var.num_desired_nodes
  launch_configuration = "${var.cluster_name}-${each.value}-lc"
  max_size             = var.max_nodes
  min_size             = var.min_nodes
  vpc_zone_identifier  = "${var.subnet_ids}"

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "${var.cluster_name}-${each.value}-asg"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}"
    value               = "owned"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "environment"
    value               = var.is_staging == 0 ? "production" : "staging"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}
```

Expected; two launch configs and two auto-scaling groups named:

- company-clustername1-web-lc
- company-clustername1-worker-lc
- company-clustername1-web-asg
- company-clustername1-worker-asg

Got:

- company-clustername1-web-lc
- company-clustername1-worker-lc

and errors like:

```
Error: Error creating AutoScaling Group: ValidationError: Launch configuration name not found - A launch configuration with the name: company-clustername1-web-lc does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: xxxx

  on modules/eks/worker-nodes.tf line 59, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "tf_eks":
  59: resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "tf_eks" {

Error: Error creating AutoScaling Group: ValidationError: Launch configuration name not found - A launch configuration with the name: company-clustername1-worker-lc does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: xxx

  on modules/eks/worker-nodes.tf line 59, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "tf_eks":
  59: resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "tf_eks" {
```

If I run `terraform apply` a second time, I get the ASGs.